Turn off default Firebase domains
I want to de-publish the base domains .web.app and firebaseapp.com. Is this possible? Well, or make a redirect to my custom domain. I'm trying to secure a website because the underlying domains don't have CloudFlare features.
I tried using redirects in firebase.json from their official documentation, but they don't respond at all:
  "redirects": [ {
    "source": "https://mydomainname.web.app{,/**}",
    "destination": "https://mydomainname.com",
    "type": 301
  }, {
    "source": "https://mydomainname.firebaseapp.com{,/**}",
    "destination": "https://mydomainname.com",
    "type": 301
  } ]


There is no way to turn off these default mappings. If you don't want to use them, simply don't tell anyone about them. See the questions I linked, and https://github.com/caprover/caprover/issues/642
